# Redirecting to a page from an external php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, redirect

I cant seem to use

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/room/room-".$link.".php");
```

to redirect to a created page after processing a form from a separate file.

### Structure

---

- carries the requested link to an external php file for processing if the file doesnt exist using jquery
- processes the link through an external php file, and create it if nonexistant
- redirect to created page, or if it already exists, redirect to the error page

However, it would seem that *header("Location: (link stuff)")* is rendered completely useless when it's processed through the external php file. Is there a way to create the chat room, but redirect to the created chat room (*if created*) as well?

Comment: hard to make sense of flow...link sent by jQuery AJAX? If so, redirect at server won't be recognized by browser. Need more detail

Comment: yeah that's about how...is there a way it would recognize it?

Comment: usually set up response to ajax so it knows to redirect using `window.location`

Comment: what about breaking the php code to insert <script>window.location.replace('link')</script and then returning to it?

Comment: would return json, parse json for what to do and get url if needed

Comment: well then I cant see a way to redirect through a php file. However, would I be able to set $_SESSION['response'] = "sent"; and check that after the form submission? like in the external file: if($_SESSION['created'] == true){ $_SESSION['response'] = "sent";}; and on page refresh, via a php section: if($_SESSION['response'] == 'sent'){ header("Location: link");};

Comment: missing the whole concept...page sends ajax....nothing on server will redirect page have to now redirect from javascript, or don't use ajax to submit in first place

Comment: I found a way. I parsed the validation in the creation form and then redirected to the php/createCustom.php if it didnt exist. Sorry about any trouble I gave you, as I'm still relatively new to this stuff. Thanks for the help, and I'll keep your replies in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a file path, not a URL path. I find using a simple `/` usually works fine

```
header("Location: /room/room-" . $link . ".php");
```

Comment: I know...I didnt mean to use $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] in that...its just secnd nature in php. however, even with a proper link,  it  doesnt redirect.